# How to keep a form from resending data?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form where you can send an email to someone, if i reload the page it sends anouther email. How do I make it so it does not do that? A forum said to change it to GET, that did not work either. mail function is not showing up.

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<textarea name="comment" cols="16.5" rows="5" style="resize: none;" maxlength="240">            </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send Comment" />
<?php
if (isset($_GET['comment'])) {
$com = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['comment']);
if (!empty($com)) {
if (strlen($com) <= 240 && strlen($com) >= 5) {                                         $mail = mail('__________', 'Comments', $com);
}
}
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: A POST form with a redirect afterwards is a much better idea - the user can refresh afterwards and it will not send additional mails.

Answer (score 2):

Send your form with POST to another page: say upload.php, then in upload.php you add this code after you have checked the form:

```
header( 'Location: form_page.php' );
```

that way the form page can be reloaded without having this issue.

Comment: when i hosted my website headers and sessions stop working, anyone know why?

Comment: Do you output anything (`echo` or similar) before `header( 'Location: form_page.php' );` ?

Comment: @RaymondKneipp Strange.. Can you specify what you mean that the headers and sessions stopped working. What error did you get?

Comment: Session Error:Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/thor3444/public_html/index.php:10) in /home3/thor3444/public_html/index.php on line 16

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home3/thor3444/public_html/index.php:10) in /home3/thor3444/public_html/index.php on line 16

Comment: Header Error:                                                               Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/thor3444/public_html/attempt.php:8) in /home3/thor3444/public_html/attempt.php on line 36

Comment: @RaymondKneipp About the session error: Have you made sure that the page source code begins with `<?php ` and not a space or something like that?

Comment: @RaymondKneipp You can take help from this SO-post about the Header error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GET` parameter (say for eg: `sent`) to the link (`index.php`) and check if it is not set before sending the mail.

```
<form action="index.php?sent=true" method="GET">
  <textarea name="comment" cols="16.5" rows="5" style="resize: none;" maxlength="240"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Comment" />
  <?php
  if (!isset($_GET['sent'])) {

     // Your code for sending the mail here...

  }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Where the operation is not idempotent, POST/redirect is generally considered best practice.

Comment: @halfer yeah, Daniel's solution is a clean one, I reckon.